# How to pivot a table of strings in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I want to pivot this table:

```
city        name
-----------------------
California  Max George
Arizona     Katty Bond
Hawaii      Jack Mick
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoBde.png)

So that the result is:

```
California   Arizona       Hawaii
-------------------------------------
Max George   Katty Bond    Jack Mick
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51kUU.png)

I am using this code:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
        city,
        CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS Name
    FROM
        employee
    WHERE 
        city IN ('Arizona', 'California', 'Hawaii')
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte AS tab1
PIVOT
    (MAX(name) FOR city IN ([Arizona], [California], [Hawaii])
    ) AS piv
```

But it shows an error at `PIVOT`.

Can someone help, please? Thanks.

Comment: Which RBDMS are you using? (mysql, presto, postgresql, etc)

Comment: Stating the obvious: neither Arizona, nor California, nor Hawaii are really **cities** - those are **states** ....

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: All clarifications should be [edit]ed into to the question (as explained in the [site guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)), not left as [comments](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); here, that meant adding the appropriate tag for the RDBMS. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: There's no need for screenshots of textual data, as [images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data.

Comment: If there is a specific error being produced, please include it in the question.

Comment: `PIVOT` is only supported in Transact-SQL on SQLServer, not PostgreSQL. You can search this site for Q&As on how to pivot on PostgreSQL, such as "[How to pivot without using PIVOT functions in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67549493/90527)".